# When I try to run commands in rails, I keep getting an error (bundle install, rails server, etc)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is the error log that the command line shows when I run the bundler and Rails commands:

```
Users/MeksProper1/Desktop/kickthelistmaster/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Bundler (NameError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Mekatron:kickthelistmaster MeksProper1$ rails server
/Users/MeksProper1/Desktop/kickthelistmaster/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Bundler (NameError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with an rvm ran out of /usr/local/rvm/, but I must ask the obvious: Have you tried `bundle exec my_command`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you might not have Bundler installed correctly or if you do, maybe an earlier version. I would try

```
gem install bundler
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't install bundler. Try this:

```
gem install bundler
```